# While installing PyQt5-tools "Preparing metadata (project.toml) ... error" error occurs on Windows

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

This is the command line that I used to install my PyQt5-tools from the pip

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install PyQt5-tools
```

After the command line is inserted into my command prompt
These messages and errors were returned

```
Collecting PyQt5-tools
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
  Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.3
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.3.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8airx5rn'
       cwd: C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i87e0y1q\pyqt5_fde282425e8e4e089b79c62a0b021979
  Complete output (29 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
  AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m1wogts2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
      project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m1wogts2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
      project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m1wogts2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 587, in setup
      self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i87e0y1q\pyqt5_fde282425e8e4e089b79c62a0b021979\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m1wogts2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m1wogts2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 234, in apply_user_defaults
      self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-m1wogts2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
      raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
  sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6e/86/d715e71771cece0e060f2ebab20f3ded067b08a0927dfb3143530cae8098/PyQt5-5.15.3.tar.gz#sha256=965ba50e7029b37f218a54ace24e87c77db3e5a9f0b83baeb21fb57b4154b838 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Legion\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8airx5rn' Check the logs for full command output.
```

What should I do to fix the error stated above.
Thank you.

Comment: use python3.9....

Comment: thank you so much!! it works